# LiDAR Scan Message Dropped by Both RVIZ2 and SLAM-Toolbox Because of TF Mismatch

Tags: ros2, rviz, gazebo-plugin

Here I am using ROS2 Dashing for a SLAM project with  a crawler off-road robot [Transbot from Yahboom.Inc](http://www.yahboom.net/study/Transbot-jetson_nano). I have created a Gazebo world file to simulate the robot in Gazebo11 (Gazebo Classic, not ignition Gazebo). The simulation runs well and I can see all the topics, including TF transformations are published correctly. The robot in simulator can also receive the command message in `/cmd_vel` topic.

However, when I trying to visualize the `/scan` topic in RViz2, I got the error messages showing constantly in console like this:

```
[rviz2-5] [ERROR] [rviz2]: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 54.15500 but the latest data is at time 54.15000, when looking up transform from frame [lidar_link] to frame [map]
```

At the same time, the `slam-toolbox` nodes also showing error messages like this:

```
[slam_toolbox-3] [INFO] [slam_toolbox]: [signalFailure] Drop message: frame 'lidar_link' at time 0.211 for reason(0)
```

As you can see, there is always a small delta between the "Requested time" (seems like the lidar message update time) and "last data time" (seems like the time of TF transform message). The gap is about 0.0100-0.0800s, some times when the time synced the lidar message would be accept by both RViz and slam-toolbox so that's why I can see the lidar result and the uncompleted map on RViz. But it just depends on fortune. In most case, the error message shown constantly and the map as well as lidar is freeze.

After some searching, I found some answer point out that this problem related to the TF time syncing. I do believe there are some errors in my TF tree that cause these issues. But I have no idea how could I fix it because the TF tree are all published by either Gazebo plugins or `static_transform_publisher` in `tf2_ros` package.

I have tried the following steps, but none of these can solve the problem:

- Reduce the LiDAR update rate in lidar sensor plugin in Gazebo world file. This can reduce the error message, even in some case, if the update rate less than 4, the map can be shown for 1 or 2 frames but then the error message shows again.
- Increase Odom publish or update rate in planar move plugin. This will cause the error becomes `Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.` and the "latest data" will be very huge (about the max value of a `double`)

Here are some of my configurations:

1. The simulation world file: gazebo.world

```xml
<sdf version='1.7'>
  <world name='default'>
  <!-- some other details ignored -->
  <model name='transbot'>
      <plugin name='planar_move' filename='libgazebo_ros_planar_move.so'>
        <ros>
          <namespace></namespace> 
          <argument>cmd_vel:=cmd_vel</argument>
          <argument>odom:=odom</argument>
        </ros>
        <update_rate>40</update_rate>
        <publish_rate>40</publish_rate>
        <!-- <publish_odom>1</publish_odom> -->
        <!-- <publish_odom_tf>1</publish_odom_tf> -->
        <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
        <robot_base_frame>base_footprint</robot_base_frame>
        <covariance_x>0.0001</covariance_x>
        <covariance_y>0.0001</covariance_y>
        <covariance_yaw>0.01</covariance_yaw>
      </plugin>
     <link name='base_footprint'>
       <sensor name="imu" type="imu">
          <!-- ensure the sensor is active (required) -->
          <always_on>true</always_on>
          <update_rate>30</update_rate>
          <plugin name="imu_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so">
            <ros>
              <!-- publish to /imu/data -->
              <namespace>/imu</namespace>
              <argument>~/out:=data</argument>
            </ros>
          </plugin>
        </sensor>
     </link>
     <link name='lidar_link'>
        <!-- Add a ray sensor, and give it a name -->
        <sensor type="gpu_ray" name="lidar">

          <plugin name="ray_sensor_plugin"
            filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
            <ros>
              <namespace>/</namespace>
              <argument>~/out:=scan</argument>
            </ros>
            <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
            <frame_name>lidar_link</frame_name>
          </plugin>
      ....
     </link>
     <frame name='base_joint' attached_to='base_footprint'>
        <pose>0 0 0.08 0 -0 0</pose>
     </frame>
     <frame name='base_link' attached_to='base_joint' />
       <pose>-0.973582 -0.992285 0 0 -0 0</pose>
   </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

2. The launch file

```py
import os
import launch
import launch.actions
import launch.substitutions
import launch_ros.actions
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from ament_index_python import get_package_share_directory

def generate_launch_description():

    use_sim_time = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='true')

    gazebo_directory = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), "launch")
    simulation_world_directory = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('simulation'), "worlds",  "gazebo.world")
    gazebo_start_cmd = launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([gazebo_directory, '/gazebo.launch.py']), launch_arguments={'world': simulation_world_directory, "verbose": "true"}.items()
    )


    rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='rviz2',
        node_executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("transbot"), 'rviz', 'transbot.rviz')],
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}]
    )

    map_to_odom_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='tf2_ros',
        node_executable='static_transform_publisher',
        arguments=['0', '0.5', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'map', 'odom']
    )

    base_to_laser_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='tf2_ros', 
        node_executable='static_transform_publisher', 
        arguments=['0', '0', '0.25', '0', '0', '0', 'base_footprint', 'lidar_link']
        )
    
    slam_toolbox_cmd = launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([get_package_share_directory('slam_toolbox'), '/launch/online_async_launch.py']), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items()
    )
    
    return launch.LaunchDescription([

        base_to_laser_node,
        map_to_odom_node,
        slam_toolbox_cmd,
        gazebo_start_cmd,
        rviz_node,
    ])
```

So my goal is successfully run the slam node and display the created map on RViz. But it seems that I can't modify most of the things in plugins or static publisher. Dose anyone know how could I make it?